# Red arrows on line numbers codelite

Tags: codelite

Just downloaded codelite, when I try to include iostream I get a red arrow on that line when hovered over it says file not found. It doesn't cause any warnings or errors however. I have tried reinstalling. If I include the string library I don't get the red arrows on it . Any help is appreciated they are very annoying.

Comment: I think Codelite 14.0.1 is still not stable, I had faced the same problem in Codelite 14.0.1 too. However, when I downgraded to 14.0.0 version which was released on Feb 20, 2020, it worked fine without any arrow message on iostream.

Answer (score 2):

Select 'Plugins'->'Language Server'->'Settings' and uncheck the box that says 'Display Diagnostics' at the bottom of the page then click OK.